# Remove margins from Shiny UI sidebarPanel() and mainPanel()

Tags: r, shiny, shinycssloaders

I have a simple Shiny app that uses the sidebarLayout(). I want to change the preset styling of this the sidebarPanel() and the mainPanel() so that the margins of the mainPanel() and sidebarPanel() disappear. In other words, I want the space between the red arrows to disappear so that the panels fill the entire viewport:

[image]

I have tried to set the margins of the sidebarPanel() and mainPanel() in their `style` elements (as in the code below), but that does not seem to change anything. Here is my code:

```
# Load packages ----
library(shiny)
library(sf)

# User interface ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width=4,
      style = "height: 90vh; overflow-y: auto; margin: 0px;",
      p("in my actual app there are a bunch of buttons and selection inputs here that are used to generate the spatial dataframe object shown in the map")
    ),
    mainPanel(width=8,
              style = "margin: 0px;",
              tags$style(HTML(".tabbable > .nav > li > a {height: 20px; padding-top:2px; padding-bottom:2px}")),
              tabsetPanel(type='tabs',
                          tabPanel("Map",
                                   tags$style(type = "text/css", "#map {height: calc(45vh) !important;}"),
                                   leafletOutput("map"),
                          ),
                          tabPanel("Table",
                                   tags$style('#table :is(th, td) {padding: 4px;}'),
                                   div(dataTableOutput(outputId = "table"), style = "height: calc(47vh); font-size: 75%; width: 100%;") 
                          )
              )
 
    )
  )
)

# Server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>%
    st_transform(crs=4326)
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      setView(-79, 35, 7) %>% 
      addTiles(group = "OpenStreetMap") %>%
      addPolygons(data = nc, 
                  color="#000000",
                  layerId = ~CNTY_ID,
                  group="Counties",
                  highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "white", 
                                                      weight = 2,
                                                      opacity=0.7,
                                                      bringToFront = TRUE)) %>%
      addLayersControl(
        baseGroups = c("OpenStreetMap"),
        overlayGroups = c("Counties"),
        options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
      )
  })
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({DT::datatable(nc,
                                                     selection= "single",
                                                     options = list(scrollX = TRUE,
                                                                    scrollY = "47vh",
                                                                    dom = 't',
                                                                    paging = FALSE))})

}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click in shiny, inspect element and select ui element to edit.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6MJW.png)

After selecting paste tags in ui

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(...),
    mainPanel(...)
  ),
  tags$head(tags$style('
    .col-sm-4 { padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; }
    .col-sm-8 { padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; }
  '))
)
```

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnnIN.png)